# Clearing data from one JTable is also deleting the another JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

I am doing an application in Java using Swing. I have two tables and I have to copy contents from one table to another (Replication.) The problem is if I clear the destination Table rows then my source table rows are also getting deleted.

If I press CopyAll then I will copy all the contents from `Table-A` to `Table-B`. If I press clear then I have to clear `Table-B`. But the problem is `Table-A` is also getting cleared.

**For copying**

```
public void copyAll() {
   TableModel tableAModel = tableA.getModel();
   tableB.setModel(tableAModel);
   repaint();
}
```

**For clearing rows (I am doing for `table-B`)**

```
public void clearTableB() {
   DefaultTableModel clearTableData = (DefaultTableModel) tableB.getModel();
   clearTableData.setNumRows(0);
}
```

I think I am getting problem while copying in copyAll() method. I am getting `tableA`'s Model and then clearing it at `clearTable()` method.

If the above `copyAll()` method is wrong please tell me how can I implement `copyAll()`, `removeTableB()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have copied the `TableModel` between the two tables. This means the two tables share the same data. If you delete the contents of the `TableModel`, both tables will loose their data.

You should create two separate `TableModel` instances, and keep them in sync (for example by using a listener as the `TableModel` fires events each time the model is updated)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But how can I create a copy of the TableModel instead of using the Original once reference in copyAll() method?

Comment: Copying the data in the table model instead of the table model itself

Comment: So you mean to say, I have to go for each ValueAt(row, column) of tableA and then paste it at corresponding cell in tableB rt? Is that the only way?

Comment: @Amarnath yes, for making a copy you will have to iterate over all the values

Answer (score 3):

In your copy version, you set the model of the first table to the second table. So the two tables share the same model. You should make a copy of the model :

```
public void copyAll() {
    final TableModel tableAModel = tableA.getModel();
    final DefaultTableModel copy = new DefaultTableModel(tableAModel.getRowCount(), 0);
    for (int column = 0; column < tableAModel.getColumnCount(); column++) {
        copy.addColumn(tableAModel.getColumnName(column));
        for (int row = 0; row < tableAModel.getRowCount(); row++)
            copy.setValueAt(tableAModel.getValueAt(row, column), row, column);
    }
    tableB.setModel(copy);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Both tables are using the same model. You have to give Table B it's own Model, copy the values manually. Your current `copyAll` method copies the *reference* to the Table Model, it doesn't copy the *contents*.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you shared the TableModel for the two tables. In the copy method, you should create a clone of the Model and use the clone for the second table.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `DefaultTableModel` You can get `Vector` of data from the model using `getDataVector()` and `clone()` it.

```
public void copyAll() {
   TableModel tableAModel = tableA.getModel(), tableModelB;
   Vector tableModelBDataVector = ((DefaultTableModel)tableAModel).getDataVector();
   int tableModelAColumnCount = tableAModel.getColumnCount();
   Vector<String> tableModelAColumnVector = new Vector<String>(tableModelAColumnCount);
   for (int i = 0; i < tableModelAColumnCount; i++)
     tableModelAColumnVector.add(tableAModel.getColumnName(i));
   tableModelB = new DefaultTableModel((Vector)tableModelBDataVector.clone(), (Vector)tableModelAColumnVector.clone());
   tableB.setModel(tableModelB);
}
```